# String que indica una operación matemática básica

Tags: anaconda, math, spyder, python-3.9

Estoy aprendiendo python y tengo un problema.
tengo que pedirle al usuario que me de una operación a realizar, ejemplo:

```
str_1 = ‘cuánto es 35 por 2’
output: 70
```

Mis operadores tienen que ser 'mas', 'menos', 'por' y 'entre', y claro si la estructura de la operación esta mal regresaría un mensaje de error

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Una disculpa, sigo estudiando y soy bastante nuevo en esto, no era mi intención el que pensaras eso,  la editare enseguida!, y en cuanto a la experiencia que mencionas, es que eh estado varias horas pegado al programa sin saber bien que hacer , creo que me falto incluir que en verdad no eh podido entender el porque salen mal mis ideas al aplicarlas, ah sido bastante frustante y creo que aquí mismo estoy formando mi experiencia de aprender a solucionar los problemas, pero muchísimas gracias por el comentario, es mas que bien recibido. :)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Si no pones lo que intentaste, como vamos a ayudar a corregir tu forma de pensar?? Si no, solamente van a darte una solucion, sin que entiendas el proceso para llegar a la misma...

Comment: si claro tienes toda la razón y estoy en ello, es verdad cuando te digo que soy muy nuevo en esto, la verdad es que intente cosas que tal vez no tengan mucho sentido :/ inclusive estoy buscando cursos o algo por el estilo, pero dame un momentito más, solo para editar este post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El usuario ingresa la frase: "Cuanto es num1 operacion num2", la gurdamos
y dividimos en tokens cada parte de la oración:

```
value = input("Por favor ingrese su operacion: ")
tokens = value.split()
```

tenemos que castear los numero introducidos como strings, así mismo como tomar la parte que es de la operación a hacer:

```
num1 = int(tokens[2])//casteo del primer numero
num2 = int(tokens[4])//casteo del segundo numero
op = tokens[3]
```

para las operaciones básicas también tenemos que declarar unas variables de tipo string para reconocerlos, y otra variable de tipo int para guardar el valor de la operación y mostrarlo:

```
str1 = "mas"
str2 = "menos"
str3 = "por"
str4 = "entre"

operation = 0
```

por ultimo haremos una serie de if's anidados, en donde si no coincide con la opción pasa la siguiente y en caso de coincidir con ninguna mandara el error:

```
if(op == str1):
    operation = num1 + num2
    print("la suma es: ", operation)
else:
    if(op == str2):
        operation = num1 - num2
        print("la resta es: ", operation)
    else:
        if(op == str3):
            operation = num1 * num2
            print("la multiplicacion es: ", operation)
        else:
            if(op == str4):
                operation = num1 / num2
                print("la division es: ", operation)
            else:
                print("ERROR!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Un código que te podría ayudar es este:

```
str_1 = int(input('cuanto es 35 por 2: '))
# la persona digita el número 70 y se guarda en el objeto str_1
# luego se imprime en consola el resultado
print(str_1)
```

Comment: Pidio exactamente lo contrario...

Comment: No sera su intención que descubra como hacerlo de manera inversa con este ejemplo?